# Using variables with commands in bash

Tags: linux, bash, variables, terminal

I'm trying to write a scenario which will input a number and then find all the files which size if bigger than this number.

So far I've got this:

```
read $size
find . -size "+{$size}c"
```

The above code doesn't work. What should I do instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this to find files bigger than your number in the variable -

```
find . -size +"${size}"c
```

You can also do something like this -

```
awk -v mysize="$size" '{if ($5>=mysize) print $9}' <(ls -l)
```

You can modify `ls -l` to provide path of a particular folder and add more options to doing search recursively.

Answer (score 2):

You should be doing `${size}c`